# React function on pageload

Tags: reactjs

I want the heartsDisplay function call on pageload, but doing it like that causes an error. It works only with on click. How do I do this in React?

Or maybe there is a way to add default value for hearts in useState hook?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css';

var heartsNum = 3;

const App = () => {
    const [hearts, setHearts] = useState("");
    
    var Score = 0;
    var customColor = {color: 'red'};

    const heartsDisplay = () => {
        if (heartsNum === 3) {
            setHearts("Hearts: ❤❤❤");
        } else if (heartsNum === 2) {
            setHearts("Hearts: ❤❤");
        } else if (heartsNum === 1) {
            setHearts("Hearts: ❤");
        } else if (heartsNum < 1) {
            setHearts("Hearts: ");
        }
    };

    heartsDisplay();

    const changeHearts = () => {
        heartsNum = heartsNum - 1;
        console.log(heartsNum);
        heartsDisplay();
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h3 className='hearts'>{hearts}</h3>
            <button className='col1' onClick={changeHearts}>Click</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Comment: on page mount can be achieved with the useEffect hook

Comment: Call `heartsDisplay` inside [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: the function must be called in an event handler for `onPageLoad`. A `useEffect` alone is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
useEffect(()=>{
    heartsDisplay();
},[]);
```

Call your function inside useEffect() hook

The useEffect Hook allows you to perform side effects in your components.

Some examples of side effects are: fetching data, directly updating the DOM, and timers.

useEffect accepts two arguments. The second argument is optional.

```
useEffect(<function>, <dependency>)
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: This does not call the function onPageLoad. `useEffect` works more like a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css';

var heartsNum = 3;

const App = () => {
    const [hearts, setHearts] = useState("");
    
    var Score = 0;
    var customColor = {color: 'red'};

    const heartsDisplay = () => {
        if (heartsNum === 3) {
            setHearts("Hearts: ❤❤❤");
        } else if (heartsNum === 2) {
            setHearts("Hearts: ❤❤");
        } else if (heartsNum === 1) {
            setHearts("Hearts: ❤");
        } else if (heartsNum < 1) {
            setHearts("Hearts: ");
        }
    };
```

call the function inside useEffect hook with no deps to run this function one time to trigger when a change in state or props put that state or props in deps array if you want to trigger the function before unmount return a function in useEffect callback do it in that function if you call the function openly in the component function it will call in all render

```
useEffect(() => {
 heartsDisplay();
},[]);

const changeHearts = () => {
    heartsNum = heartsNum - 1;
    console.log(heartsNum);
    heartsDisplay();
}

return (
    <div>
        <h3 className='hearts'>{hearts}</h3>
        <button className='col1' onClick={changeHearts}>Click</button>
    </div>
)
```

}

export default App

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the use of useState. Default value for useState is the default value for the hearts variable.

What you are looking for is probably the [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).
It's default behavior is

> similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate

which basically leads to on page load behavior.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './App.css';

var heartsNum = 3;

const App = () => {
    const [hearts, setHearts] = useState("");


    var Score = 0;
    var customColor = {color: 'red'};

    useEffect(() => {
        heartsDisplay();
      },[]);


    const heartsDisplay = () => {
        if (heartsNum === 3) {
            setHearts("Hearts: ❤❤❤");
        } else if (heartsNum === 2) {
            setHearts("Hearts: ❤❤");
        } else if (heartsNum === 1) {
            setHearts("Hearts: ❤");
        } else if (heartsNum < 1) {
            setHearts("Hearts: ");
        }
    };

    const changeHearts = () => {
        heartsNum-=1;
        console.log(heartsNum);
        heartsDisplay();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div></div>
            <h3  className='hearts'>{hearts}</h3>
            <button className='col1' onClick={changeHearts}>Click</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```